# how query gerrit patch numbers for topic or hashtags with spaces

Tags: gerrit

tried all variants, not one working.
got topic with name "test 1" and hashtag "test 1", trying to retrieve all patch numbers for them, not 'topic' or 'hashtag' option worked :

```
ssh -p 29418 myserver gerrit query --patch-sets topic:"'test 1'"
ssh -p 29418 myserver gerrit query --patch-sets topic:"test 1"
ssh -p 29418 myserver gerrit query --patch-sets topic:'test 1'
```

But same result:

```
type: stats
rowCount: 0
runTimeMilliseconds: 2
moreChanges: false
```

may be encrypt space somehow ?
If names without spaces all working ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use one of these options:

```
ssh -p 29418 myserver gerrit query --patch-sets topic:\\\"test 1\\\"
```

Or

```
ssh -p 29418 myserver gerrit query --patch-sets "topic:{test 1}"
```

Comment: Thanks for `{ }` variant - it helped me after trying all possible escape sequences.